# Change default test class name suffix in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

By default when I generate test class in IDEA it has "Test" suffix. As I usually use Spock I want to change it to be "Spec" by default. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Did find a way to do that? I'm not sure if my workaround (which I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278906/is-it-possible-to-change-default-class-name-template-for-junit4-test-in-intellij/36285995#36285995 would apply to your case, but maybe it's worth to look at.

Comment: Not possible right now. See - and vote - here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154382

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's finally possible with the IntelliJ 2018.1:

> With the IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1, you can customize a test class template and create a test class with Test as a prefix. Go to Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation, and choose how the test class name should be generated. By default, the IDE creates a test class with the Test as a suffix.

Above is from [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/01/intellij-idea-starts-2018-1-early-access-program/)

Answer (score 0):

Below red box means 'Test' suffix.
[image]

You can change it to'Spec'.