# Is it possible to change default class name template for junit4 test in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

We have a name convention for our test classes:

---

For unit test : TestMyCoolClazz

For integration tests : ITestMyCoolClazz

---

But whenever Intellij Idea prompts 'Create Test' dialog window, class name is always MyCoolClazzTest. So basically it adds a word 'Test' at the and of a class name.

So can a change it?

[image]

Comment: I think what you want is the feature requested here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86808.  You could vote for it or add additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround using [JUnitGenerator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3064?pr=idea) plugin, maybe it will suit your needs. Thing is, it doesn't allow to customize the mentioned 'Create Test' popup invoked by Shift+Ctrl+T, but you can customize the way how IDE generates tests by pressing Alt+Insert and then selecting JUnitTest -> JUnit 3/4.

So if it would be sufficient, there's the way: after installing this plugin, you can find JUnit Generator entry in Settings under the 'Other Settings' section. In a file template window, there is an editable test template, as shown below:

[image]

There is a line:

`#set( $testClass="${entry.className}Test")`

You can change it to, for example:

`#set( $testClass="Test${entry.className}")` or `#set( $testClass="ITest${entry.className}")`

and that's it. I also noticed that IntelliJ restart is required.